# How to access previous input element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, closest

I'm trying to access an input element so I can disable an input button when another one is clicked. For some reason I'm unable to get it after trying a few dozen different methods.

I'd like to disable the 'Checkout' button when the 'Absent' button is clicked.

Here is the HTML and Javascript

```js
$(document).on('click','.absent',function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var t = $(this);
 
   //t.parent('td.checkout').prop('disabled', true);
    t.closest('.checkout').prop('disabled', true);
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <input type="button" class="checkin" value="Check-in" id="checkin_datetime" name="checkin_datetime">
</td>
<td class="nowrap">
  <input class="checkout" type="button" value="Check-out" id="checkout_datetime" name="checkout_datetime">
</td>
<td class="nowrap">
  <input class="absent Y" type="button" value="Mark Absent" id="absent_flag" name="absent_flag">
</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cary/pjatf31y/9/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my logic, using closest, not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest travels up the DOM, but targeting `.checkout` will fail because that's not an ancestor of the button being clicked. Use `t.closest('td').prev().find('.checkout').prop('disabled', true);`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.absent', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var t = $(this);
  t.closest('td').prev().find('.checkout').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="checkin" value="Check-in" id="checkin_datetime" name="checkin_datetime">
    </td>
    <td class="nowrap">
      <input class="checkout" type="button" value="Check-out" id="checkout_datetime" name="checkout_datetime">
    </td>
    <td class="nowrap">
      <input class="absent Y" type="button" value="Mark Absent" id="absent_flag" name="absent_flag">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked. I also noticed that the HTML structure had to be valid for it to work. My snippet didn't have the <table> or <tr> tags and that was preventing your code from working.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="checkin" value="Check-in" id="checkin_datetime" name="checkin_datetime">
        </td>
        <td class="nowrap">
            <input class="checkout" type="button" value="Check-out" id="checkout_datetime" name="checkout_datetime">
        </td>
        <td class="nowrap">
            <input class="absent Y" type="button" value="Mark Absent" id="absent_flag" name="absent_flag">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.absent',function(e) {
                $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('.checkout').prop('disabled', true);
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Hope this helps" does not explain the solution.