# Find an HTML element given 'this' object that is not child of

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, onclicklistener

Maybe the question is very odd..
Given this piece of HTML

```
<div class="team-item wow fadeInUpQuick" data-wow-delay=".2s">
    <figure class="team-profile">
        <img src="assets/img/team/Roby-piccola.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption data-team="roby" class="">
            <div class="details">
                <p class="content-white">Some text</p>
            </div>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div class="info">
        <h2>Name<span class="mobile-visible">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span><i data- 
           team='roby' id="more-info" class="fas fa-info mobile-visible"></i>
        </h2>
     </div>
 </div>
```

When in mobile device, the `<i>` element is visible and onclick event attached to it. When click on it I want that the `<figcation>` get `opacity: 1` (default is `opacity: 0`;).
I have 12 of team-item `<div>` and how can I know which `<figcaption>` I need to display given this object in the onclick event fired?
I solved with `[data-team]` attribute, but it seems to me hard-coded solution. There is a way to be dynamic?
Thanks

Comment: `$(this).closest('.team-item').find('fig-caption')`? - [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my logic, using closest, not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work)

Comment: how stupid that i am, so simple :-( Thanks