# Cannot grab text in the above div

Tags: jquery

In the snippet below, I'd like to get `Text to grab` whenever `Edit` button is clicked:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="pbody">
        <p>Text to grab</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row treply">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <p>Hi there</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <a class="quote btn" href="#">reply</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <a class="edit btn" href="#">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

There are several divs with `pbody` class, but I'd like to get the immediate one above the clicked `Edit` Button.

I have tried many jQuery tricks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".edit").click(function () {
    let postText = $(this).closest(".pbody").children("p").text();
     console.log("postText is:", postText);
  });
});
```

but none work. So appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work

Comment: `.pbody` is not a parent of the `.edit`

Comment: @Taplar right, I edited the question.

Comment: Maybe something like `$(this).parent().parent().find('.pbody')[0].children('p').text();`? Pretty gross, but ideally you'd add an id or class to the p tag of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't traversing the DOM according to your HTML. Try this instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".edit").click(function() {
    let postText = $(this).closest(".row.treply").prev('br').prev('.row').find('div.pbody > p').text();
    console.log("postText is:", postText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="pbody">
      <p>Text to grab</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row treply">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <p>Hi there</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <a class="quote btn" href="#">reply</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <a class="edit btn" href="#">Edit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Refs:

- [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)