# jQuery: prev(child selector) is not giving the desired result

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the child selector inside the prev method however i am not able to get the desired result.

```js
$( ".collapse" ).prev( ".my-row > .panel-heading" ).first().css( "background", "yellow" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-row">
    <p class="panel-heading">1</p>
    <p class="panel-heading">2</p>
    <p class="panel-heading">3</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse">Hello</div>
```

first paragraph of class panel-heading i want to change its background.

Comment: You need to two step it.  The `.panel-heading` elements are not siblings, and `prev()` is not intended to evaluate against sibling children.  It simply checks the siblings to see if they match the selector.  And siblings will never match a nested selector string.

Comment: This behavior is similar to why `closest()` does not work with nested selectors.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
$(".collapse").prev(".my-row").find(".panel-heading").first().css("background", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-row">
  <p class="panel-heading">1</p>
  <p class="panel-heading">2</p>
  <p class="panel-heading">3</p>
</div>
<div class="collapse">Hello</div>
```

> ... the `.prev()` method searches for the predecessor of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

- https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Use `.prev()` to find the item you want and then search it's children with `.find()` or `.children()`.