# jQuery get clicked elements parent and then its child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that's hidden, when i link is clicked i want that form to be shown.

```
{% for comment in comments %}
                        <li class="depth-1 comment">
                            <div class="comment__avatar">
                                {#<img width="50" height="50" class="avatar" src="{{ comment.user.profile_image.url }}" alt="">#}
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment__content">
                                <div class="comment__info">
                                    <cite>{{ comment.user.username }}</cite>
                                    <div class="comment__meta">
                                        <time class="comment__time">{{ comment.created_at }}</time>
                                        <a class="reply">Reply</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment__text" id="data">
                                    <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="respond reply-comment" style="display: none">
                                    <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm reply-form" method="post" action="">
                                        <div class="message form-field reply-field">
                                            {{ comment_form.text }}
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="submit btn--primary" style="float: right;">
                                            Submit
                                        </button>
                                    </form> <!-- end form -->
                                </div> <!-- end respond -->
                            </div>
                        </li> <!-- end comment level 1 -->
                    {% endfor %}
```

When `reply` is clicked,  i need `reply-comment`'s `style` to be "". How can i achive that?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work

Comment: [Traversing | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to traverse the DOM to find the `.reply-comment` related to the clicked `.reply` element. In this case you would do that by using `closest()`, to get the nearest common parent, then `find()`.

You should also avoid using inline `style` attributes. Place your styling in external stylesheets so that it can be overridden much more simply.

In addition you should not put `id` attributes in HTML generated by a loop. This is because it creates multiple elements with the same `id` which is invalid. Either remove the `id`, or use `class` attributes to group elements by common behaviour.

Lastly clickable `a` elements should always have an `href` attribute. This is because in some older browsers the `click` event would not be raised unless it's present. You can stop the URL from being updated when this happens by using `preventDefault()` in the event handler.

With all that said, try the below example. Note that I removed some of the HTML from this to make it a little shorter.

```js
$('.reply').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.comment__content').find('.reply-comment').show();
});
```

```css
.comment__avatar .avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.reply-comment {
  display: none;
}

.submit.btn-primary {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="depth-1 comment">
    <div class="comment__avatar">
      {#<img class="avatar" src="{{ comment.user.profile_image.url }}" alt="">#}
    </div>
    <div class="comment__content">
      <div class="comment__info">
        <div class="comment__meta">
          <a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="respond reply-comment">
        <form name="contactForm" method="post" action="">
          <div class="message form-field reply-field">{{ comment_form.text }}</div>
          <button type="submit" class="submit btn--primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="depth-1 comment">
    <div class="comment__avatar">
      {#<img class="avatar" src="{{ comment.user.profile_image.url }}" alt="">#}
    </div>
    <div class="comment__content">
      <div class="comment__info">
        <div class="comment__meta">
          <a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="respond reply-comment">
        <form name="contactForm" method="post" action="">
          <div class="message form-field reply-field">{{ comment_form.text }}</div>
          <button type="submit" class="submit btn--primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .closet for find parent by class name, and then use .find for find child. Finally use removeAttr("style") for remove style

```
 $('.reply').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('div[class="comment__content"]').find('.reply-comment').removeAttr("style");
 })
```

Comment: `div[class="comment__content"]'`... or just `.comment__content`

Comment: ^^^ forcing an attribute selector on a class will result in the browser not being able to apply performance gains against the available class selector, and can result in a DOM scan, as an attribute can be on any node.