# jquery - get the id of the closest element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code which is used to edit an input when clicked on it and then save in the db.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.editable').on('click', function() {
          var that = $(this);
          if (that.find('input').length > 0) {
              return;
          }
          var currentText = that.text();
          var $input = $('<input>').val(currentText);
          $(this).append($input);

          // Handle outside click
          $(document).click(function(event) {
              if(!$(event.target).closest('.editable').length) {
                  if ($input.val()) {
                      that.text($input.val());

                      var div_id = $(this).closest('#commentbox').attr('id');
                      div_id = div_id.replace('comment-', '');
                      alert(div_id);
                      $.post( "updateComment.php", {id: div_id,message: $input.val()})
                  }
                  that.find('input').remove();
              }
          });
      });
    });
```

Var div_id is not retrieving it at all.
And I want to retrieve only the number from the id from this however it does not work. I've been trying several solutions and this last one isn't working either

```
    <div id="comments">
       <div class="commentbox" id="comment-90">...</div>
       <div class="commentbox" id="comment-91">...</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `this` is the document within the document click event handler.  There is nothing above the document, save for the window.  This code is using an anti-pattern of creating an event listener within an event handler.  This will most likely create duplicate bindings, which are for the majority of instances undesired.

Comment: Related (but you have other issues also): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work

Answer (score 1):

This part of code is basically a problem:

```js
var div_id = $(this).closest('#commentbox').attr('id');
```

Firstly, you are trying to get closest element from `document` as `this` points to `document` in that part of your code (you meant probably `event.target` instead). 
Secondly, you are trying to find the closest element with `id == 'commentbox'`, as this is what `#<selector>` means. You should use some other attribute for that purpose - probably best would be some class selector and then use the `.attr('id')` on it.