# Selecting one <td> from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table which consist of user added data. All the 's added are added with a equal button. Like this:

```
<td> 
  <form action="newBet.jsp" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <input class="button betButton1" id="Won" type="submit" name="W" value="&#10004;"/>

          <div class="closeEarlyForm" style="display:none;">
            <input class="form-control" name="update1" type="number"/>
            <input class="button betButton1" type="submit" name="update" value="Close early"/>
          </div>

       <input class="closeEarlyLink" type="button" value="&#9998; Close early?"/>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
</td>
```

This wokrs fine. Now, I want to add some jquery which toggle the hidden div element. This is where I run into troubles. I can't seem show the div element only on the clicked element. Instead it shows the hidden div element on all the td's.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".closeEarlyLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".closeEarlyForm").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

I know that my problem is that I select all the elements with the class, but I cant figure out how to only toggle/select the hidden element on the specific td.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work  You should use closest() to get the fieldset and then find your nested div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `this` keyword with `parent()` and `find()`:

```
$(this).parent().find(".closeEarlyForm").fadeToggle();
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".closeEarlyLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find(".closeEarlyForm").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td> 
  <form action="newBet.jsp" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <input class="button betButton1" id="Won" type="submit" name="W" value="&#10004;"/>

          <div class="closeEarlyForm" style="display:none;">
            <input class="form-control" name="update1" type="number"/>
            <input class="button betButton1" type="submit" name="update" value="Close early"/>
          </div>

       <input class="closeEarlyLink" type="button" value="&#9998; Close early?"/>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
</td>
```

Comment: thank you! This worked perfectly. Hope you dont mind, but "this" keyword in the code above points towards what? I can't really make sense of it, but it works :-) Just really wont to understand why!

Comment: @egx, `this` keyword refers to the currently clicked `.closeEarlyLink`:)

Comment: Got it. And then it will select the parent of that element which have closeEarlyForm class. Makse sense! Thank you :-)