# Find document element by class name closest to the button that is being clicked

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a little mini html game that uses Backbone.

The main page has multiple `<div>` tags with the class name of "monsterName".

There is a button near it, that, when clicked, I want to get the text that is inside the "monsterName" `<div>`

I am trying to use the `closest()` method from the WebAPI to find the closest `<div>` to the clicked button that has a class name of "monsterName".

Here this will help you see my HTML page generated by the view and template:

```
<div id="root">

<div id="title">Monster Hunting 101</div>

<div class="monsterArea">
    <div class="monsterName">Orc</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="findMonster">Monster Hunting</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="monsterArea">
    <div class="monsterName">Dragon</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="findMonster">Monster Hunting</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="monsterArea">
    <div class="monsterName">Giant</div>
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="findMonster">Monster Hunting</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The view has code that fires when the button ".findMonster" is clicked:

```
events: {
    "click .findMonster": "startHunt"
},
```

When that button is clicked, it fires this function:

```
startHunt: function (e) {
    const $closestMonster = e.closest('.monsterName');
    console.log($closestMonster.innerHTML);
    ...do some stuff with the text in the monsterName...
}
```

So the view is working and the button works, and it fires off the **startHunt** event.

But it always gives me this error:
Uncaught TypeError: e.closest is not a function

Comment: `closest` is a jQuery method, not a native Element method, as far as I am aware.  If the `e.target` is the button, `e.target.parentNode` would be it's parent `<div>` and then you would need possibly `.previousSibling` to get the monsertName div.

Comment: closest would work on the DOM elements only but you are trying to use it on event Object, try document.querySelector(e.target).closest('.monsterName')

Comment: @Taplar hi thanks I do have the jquery library loaded.  e.target.parentNode returns the node with a class of "controls".  I am hoping to get the closest node with a class of 'monsterName'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my logic, using closest, not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work)

Comment: Since you do have jQuery loaded, if you want to use jQuery to do this, this is a duplicate.  Keeping in mind you will have to `$(e.target)` before using closest()

Comment: @Vishal thanks but that gives me error: `Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLButtonElement]' is not a valid selector`

Comment: @Vishal `e.target` is an Element, not a selector.  Since you already have a reference to it, there's no need to use querySelector to find it at all.

Comment: @Taplar Did you find the answer to your question helpful?  Did you use this method? `var $firstNameLabel = $(e.target).closest('.form-group').find('.firstName');`

Comment: I'm sorry?  I didn't ask a question. @SkyeBoniwell

Comment: because closest works on the ancestors so you can't directly use it with ('.monsterName'), you need to use closest with ('.monsterArea') and then find ('.monsterName') there and yes to correct my previous answer e.target should be used only without document.querySelector or $ in case of jQuery

Comment: @Taplar sorry I meant the link to the question [Why does my logic, using closest, not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599051/why-does-my-logic-using-closest-not-work)

Comment: @Vishal thank you so should I chain together both sides like this? `const $closestMonster = e.closest('.monsterArea').find('.monsterName')` ?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes just use (e.target).closest instead of e.closest

Comment: If the problem is solved in above comments, please close/delete the issue. If not please update accordingly

Comment: @TJ how can I update it to show that Taplar solution fixed it?   I don't want to delete because this thread may be useful to people seeking similar help.

Comment: You can maybe [edit] and add something like `[Fixed]` , `[Solved]` etc in title, or Add the solution (and tick the "community wiki" checkmark if you don't want the credit for it) as an answer and accept it. So people don't have to read the question, comment etc only to find out it is already solved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `closest()` and `find()` worked for this problem:

```
const $closestMonster = e.closest('.monsterArea').find('.monsterName');
```